# Оптимизируется ли Include в EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Вопрос заключается в том, оптимизирует ли загрузку данных EF Core?
Конкретно о чем я говорю, есть такой код загрузки заказов и контрагентов у заказов:

```
await dbContext.Orders.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Include(x => x.Counterparty).ToListAsync();
```

Вопрос в том, что если у меня будет, например, 5 разных заказов, но с одним контрагентом, то он выгрузит 5 раз одного и того-же контрагента или будет искать ссылку в кэше и будет использовать её?
Пытался найти какую-то информацию в гугле - не смог, может что-то не так искал?
Буду рад любым ответам.

Comment: Что вам мешает запустить это и поглядеть sql запрос?

Comment: По SQL запросу будет понятно, что он берет всё и сразу, повторения будут конечно, но суть в том, что сохранит ли он все одинаковые объекты в себе или нет?

Comment: не понял, какая разница? Если этого нет в доке по efcore, значит это знать не надо и оно может в любой версии поменяться.

Comment: Ну, просто у меня есть, например, таблица со статусами заказов, будет 1000 заказов и у всех будет 1 статус, а при выборке он что, загрузит 1000 одинаковых статусов в себя? это же утечка памяти неимоверная, да и нагрузка будет не хилая (таких полей может быть не одно).

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Загрузит ли он в себя 1000 одинаковых объектов, соответствующих одной записи в базе - нет, не загрузит, ef реализует identity map, насколько я знаю, так что одна запись в базе - один объект

Comment: Попробуйте через .Select( => ) указать нужные поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации [Eager loading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading) есть предупреждение Caution о возможных проблемах с производительностью.

В документации [Split queries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) описана причина проблемы. Данные при загрузке могут дублироваться, как раз чего вы и опасаетесь.
Способ её устранения - использовать разделённые запросы: `.AsSplitQuery()`.

Полезные ссылки:

[Change Tracker Debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/debug-views) - так можно посмотреть, как обращения происходят к отслеживаемым сущностям.

[Accessing Tracked Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/entity-entries) - способы использования отслеживаемых объектов.

Comment: То, что нужно. по всей видимости, благодарю)

Comment: Топикастер вроде как по наличие identity map спрашивал. Данные могут дублироваться при выборке, но на уровне объектов вроде как дубликатов не будет